# Windows Script Host and JavaScript; I think I'm missing something blatantly obvious

Tags: javascript, wsh

I'm stuck on a "Hello World" program.

Not even kidding.

```
alert("Hello World");
```

I have searched, and I can't find any reason this wouldn't execute in WSH, but it won't; I'm assuming I've screwed up unbelievably moronically.

Related question, are there any good JavaScript tutorials which deal with WSH rather than browsers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hello World in WSH is:

```
WSH.Echo("Hello world");
WSH.Quit();
```

Honestly, I would try to learn Javascript in a more traditional environment, like a browser or Javascript console, and then take what you know over to WSH. Here's an overview of WSH that will get you started, though. http://www.pctools.com/guides/article/id/2/

Comment: It's `WScript`, not `WSH`.